# Prove that $f\equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. Suppose that $\int_c^d f(x)dx=0$ holds for every $a\le c<d\le b$. Show that $f$ must be identically zero on $[a,b]$.

I have solved the problem as stated in the answer posted by me, but a better solution will be appreciated. And is the answer rigorous enough?

Answer (score 3):

Given that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Also, it is given that $\int_c^df(x)dx=0$, holds for every $a\le c<d\le b$. Now let us assume that $f(x)>0$ for some $x_1\in(a,b)$. Then since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]\implies \exists \delta>0,$ such that $f(x)>0$ $\forall, x\in(x_1-\delta,x_1+\delta).$ Now let $x_2>x_3\in(x_1-\delta,x_1+\delta)$.

Now applying MVT for integrals on the interval $[x_3,x_2]$ for the function $f$, we can conclude that $\exists c\in(x_3,x_2)$, such that $$f(c)=\frac{\int_{x_3}^{x_2}f(x)dx}{x_2-x_3}.$$ But $\int_{x_3}^{x_2}f(x)dx=0$, which implies that $f(c)=0$. But, since $c\in(x_3,x_2)\implies f(c)>0.$ Contradiction. Therefore, $\nexists x\in(a,b)$, such that $f(x)>0$.

A similar argument tells that, $\nexists x\in(a,b)$, such that $f(x)<0$.

Therefore, $\forall x\in(a,b), f(x)=0$.

This also implies that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=0$.

Now since $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $b$, implies $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

This implies that $\forall x\in[a,b]$, we have, $f(x)=0$.

Comment: That's a bit clumsy. For $x_0\in(a,b)$ assume $y=f(x_0)>0$, then $f(x_0)-y/2>0$. Hence, by continuity there is an open set $(c,d)\subset (a,b)$ where $f(x_0)-y/2 > 0$, so $f(x_0) > y/2$. It follows that $\intop_c^d f(x)dx \ge y(d-c)/2$.

Comment: +1 for solving it yourself and glad to know that you seek alternatives to your approach (+1 for question too).

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is fine. But here is a little bit different solution:

Let's assume that $f \neq 0$. This implies that $\exists c \in (a, b) $ so that $f(c) \neq 0$. (It can't be non-zero at the endpoints only because of the continuity). Let's assume that $f(c) >0$. Then, from the definition of continuity, we have that $\exists \varepsilon > 0$ so that $f(x) > \frac{f(c) } {2}$ on a interval centered at $c$ with radius $\varepsilon$. But then we can bound the integral from below of $f$ on this interval by $\frac{f(c)} {2} 2\varepsilon$, which is positive.

Comment: Your remark about end points is not clear. If $f$ is not identically $0$ then it means that there is a $c\in[a, b] $ with $f(c) \neq 0$. I don't see how continuity prevents $c$ being an end point.

Comment: There is a $c\in[a, b] $ with $f(c) \neq 0$ then by continuity at $c$ we have a subinterval $[p, q] \subseteq [a, b] $ with $p<q$ and $c\in[p, q] $ and $f$ has same sign as that of $c$ in whole of $[p, q] $ and the integral over this interval is non-zero.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What I wanted to say is that we can't have that $f$ is non-zero at the endpoints only, because continuity will guarantee that it will have the same sign in a ball around the endpoint.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted. +1